# Synchronize timestamps in Jenkins output console

Tags: jenkins, timestamp

I am facing the following problem:
Jenkins slaves are deployed in AWS, in different regions.The console output of builds contains timestamps, in the timezone where each node/slave belongs.
Is there a way to have timestamps in the same timezone as Jenkins server?

Comment: Did you find any solution to this yet ?